# Activerecord store only returns empty hash after rails 5 upgrade

Tags: activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am in the process of upgrading a rails 4.2 application to rails 5. One of the models uses an ActiveRecord::Store. When retrieving records after the upgrade, said store only returns an empty Hash. I have no idea why that's happening and wasn't able to find anything in the changelog. So any help and explanation would be appreciated.

Here's the output of the rails 4 console:

`=> #<StoredDataQuery ..., config: {"start_date"=>6, "end_date"=>0, ...>`

and rails 5:

`=> #<StoredDataQuery ..., config: {}, ...`

psql output:

```
development=# SELECT config FROM stored_data_queries WHERE id=1;
                   config
---------------------------------------------
 --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters+
 start_date: 6                              +
 end_date: 0                                +
 interval: day                              +

(1 row)
```

Looking at the SQL output, I'm suspecting it has something to do with the data being serialized as `ActionController::Parameters`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: After a few experiments I found out that rails 5 stores objects as `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`. So now the question is, whether there's a better way than raw sql to transform the stored objects.

Comment: Here's how to fix it in sql (postgres) `UPDATE stored_data_queries SET config = replace(config, 'ActionController::Parameters', 'ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to fix it in sql (postgres):

`UPDATE stored_data_queries SET config = replace(config, 'ActionController::Parameters', 'ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess');`

Comment: i would say be very cautious if running this data migration on large tables. We had 9 million records in one table and it took forever, we had to kill and everything.

Answer (score 2):

Same here, after Upgrading [Zammad](https://github.com/zammad/zammad) from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0. After some research I found out that active record is only reading ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess from store anymore (other classes are skipped).

So for migration you can overwrite `ActiveRecord::Store::IndifferentCoder.as_indifferent_hash` in a migration, read all related records from database and just save them back (then all ActionController::Parameters are converted to ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess).

For me the following migration (under Rails 5.0) has worked to convert all ActionController::Parameters to ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:

```
require 'active_record/store'
module ActiveRecord
  module Store
    class IndifferentCoder
      def self.as_indifferent_hash(obj)
        case obj
        # re-enable using ActionController::Parameters in stores,
        # convert them to ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
        # at reading from db
        when ActionController::Parameters
          obj.permit!.to_h
        # /re-enable
        when ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
          obj
        when Hash
          obj.with_indifferent_access
        else
          ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class FixedStoreUpgrade45 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    [Macro, Taskbar, Calendar, Trigger, Channel, Job, PostmasterFilter, Report::Profile, Setting, Sla, Template].each do |class_name|
      class_name.all.each do |record|
        begin
          record.save!
        rescue => e
          Rails.logger.error "Unable to save/update #{class_name}.find(#{record.id}): #{e.message}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Data migration is not necessary if the patch is done. And i would say be very cautious if running this data migration on large tables. We had 9 million records in one table and it took forever, we had to kill and everything. Then we avoided migration and used only the patch provided above. Works as of now.

Comment: I also found the module patch was successful in resolving this issue, without the FixedStoreUpgrade45 migration.  Currently testing, but it looks good so far.